# No module named 'flask_bootstrap'

Tags: flask, flask-bootstrap

Though i install flask_bootstrap with pip command and also tried it installing from tar package but when i import with the statement i.e from flask_bootstrap import bootstrap it gives an error of no module name flask_bootstrap . Please help any one

[Module Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFoCe.png)

[Pip install command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBAZp.png)

Comment: Can you post the output of `pip install` command that you ran, and also the results of `import flask_bootstrap` from the Python console?

Comment: Yes i have provided it

Comment: After doing pip list In the terminal its showing Flask-Bootstrap but when tried to import it with the same name its giving  the following error:                                                                                     1)Unexpected token ' - '                                                          2) unexpectedtoken 'import' 3) Unresolved import 'Flask'

Comment: You appear to have both python 3.7 and 3.8 installed. You should try using a `venv`

Comment: It's a good idea to post the output in text as well. People can see the problem faster without needing to open a picture and they can copy-paste the text if needed. Also the StackOverflow website and search engines can index it better with that text output.